# Properties of a term rewrite rule

Tags: term-rewriting

While doing some bibliography on term-rewriting, I often found these two properties to define a term rewrite rule (see for example [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a19e/9d5f7411b6904c27e6ea7e9fb8177b7cc61f.pdf) and [this one](https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/det/Papers/tgr_survey.pdf)):

> A term rewrite rule is a pair $\langle l,r\rangle$ of terms, written $l \rightarrow r$, such that
>
> 1) $l$ is not a variable
>
> 2) all variables in $r$ occur also in $l$.

I fail to understand the reason of these properties, at least for the definition of a rule (I can see why they would matter for termination or confluence proofs). Why a term rewriting system could not contain a rule such as $x \rightarrow x + 1 - 1$ or $x \rightarrow x + y - y$ ? Just to provide some context, I'm trying to use TRS in the context of obfuscation, where such rewritings have meaning.

Can someone explain why rules composing a TRS would need these properties?

Comment: Indeed the rules are sufficient for the term rewrite system to be terminating.  This observation is known as Lankford Theorem. Cf. Section 4 of the Rewriting chapter by Dershowitz and Plaisted from the Handbook of Automated Reasoning http://rewriting.loria.fr/documents/rewriting.pdf

Comment: Which theorem are you referring to? The rules are by no means sufficient for termination, e.g. $c\rightarrow c$ for some constant $c$ satisfies the above rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I didn't know this one. But does this means that we could create a non-terminating TRS with rules not verifying these properties?
@cody : I think the theorem is 4.6, even if it's not clear for me why ordering would be somehow equivalent to the two properties

Comment: It is not. The existence of a simplification ordering *implies* both rules 1. and 2., since in a simplification ordering $l>x$ for all $x$ in $l$, so in particular $l \not> r$ if it violates either rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is no obstacle to *define* a rewrite system as above, and a few sources do indeed require rules 1. and 2. only as additional hypotheses.

However the hypotheses are almost always *necessary* (but not sufficient!) for both termination and confluence, which is indeed the main object of study of rewriting as a field.

Perhaps it's useful to remind why this is the case:

Termination:

1. If $x\rightarrow t$ is allowed as a rule, then *any* term $u$ rewrites to $t[u/x]$. In particular, the system is non-terminating.
2. If $l\rightarrow r$ and $r$ contains a fresh variable $y$ not in $l$, then for example, $l\rightarrow r[l/y]$, and so the system is non-terminating.

Confluence:

1. Take $x \rightarrow f(x)$ and $g(a)\rightarrow b$. Then
   $$ g(f(a))\leftarrow g(a)\rightarrow b$$
   for instance, breaking confluence. In particular, you can "insert" an $f$ around any term you like, which makes confluence very hard to satisfy.
2. If there are constants $a$ and $b$, then given the rule $f(x)\rightarrow g(y)$, you get
   $$ g(a)\leftarrow f(x)\rightarrow g(b)$$
   again, breaking confluence.

---

Now every theorem involving either termination or confluence *could* be prefaced with "assuming 1. and 2. holds, ..." but it makes sense to restrict your attention to systems where the theorems aren't trivially false. I don't think anyone would be shocked by a paper which lifts these restrictions though, at least condition 2. (condition 1. really creates anarchy). Condition 2. is mostly about non-determinism, for which rewriting is a nice framework in general.

There are *some* systems in which free variables can appear in the RHS, but usually not *any* fresh variable $y$ is allowed: there are additional *constraints* which need to be satisfied, e.g.

$$f(x) \rightarrow  f(y)\ \mid\ 0\leq y < x $$

where $x$ and $y$ are allowed to be integers. These types of systems are called **constraint rewriting systems** and are extensively studied.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm actually not considering termination or confluence properties for obfuscation, as it's not really the purpose. But as I use rewriting systems for _deobfuscation_ (in my case, simplification of expressions) where it is much closer to "classic" rewriting (i-e it's possible to prove termination / confluence), I wanted to know if the notions and notations could be used for obfuscation, even if that's just for the definitions and not the theorems, etc. Would you have a reference with a definition of rewrite rule that does not include the two properties?

Comment: I'm afraid nothing comes to mind at the moment. It's probably useful to note that *[production rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_(computer_science))* in the classical theory of grammars allow these kinds of rules, more or less.

Classically the theory was described for strings, but the formalism easily extends to trees (unsurprisingly called [Tree Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_automaton)), which I don't know much about.

Comment: Production rules definitely seem worth investigating!